# Get phone number associated with SIM for android device

Tags: android, flutter

Currently I am using TelephonyManager for fetching phone numbers associated with SIM cards but it gives you numbers which we have set in SIM settings, so user can change that number after going in SIM setting and gives wrong output
Also some devices doesn't have phone numbers which are shown in SIM settings and hence it doesn't give any output in such case

Please help if anyone knows anything around it

Comment: You ideally shouldn't be doing this due to user privacy. Even user:12183825 suggests you get the device ID. You should not do that either. Instead you should get the per app assigned UUID as shown here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html.
Also do note, I doubt Google will allow you to publish an app with these permissions.